bash script for shortening a filename to at most 'n' length but without clipping whole words
I've got a bash script that looks inside a folder and finds all files with filenames with length greater than n and shortens the filename to n.
I want to have it shorten the filename to the length of n, but in the event that doing so ends up clipping a word, instead of clipping the word just remove that clipped word entirely and end the new filename at the last character that's not a space.
Example:
sample file name so long wrangling roose turns bridge.txt
When I run the script I may get:
sample file name so long wrangling ro.txt
I'd like it to be:
sample file name so long wrangling.txt
This is my current script that just clips words:
#!/bin/bash

export n=120 # length of filename desired
find . -type f                      \
     ! -name '.*'                   \
       -regextype egrep             \
     ! -regex '.*\.[^/.]{'"$n"',}'  \
       -regex '.*[^/]{'$((n+1))',}' \
       -execdir bash -c '
    for f in "${@#./}"; do
        ext=${f#"${f%.*}"}
        mv -- "$f" "${f:0:n-${#ext}}${ext}"
    done' bash {} +


I would - for each filename - create an array of all words and then loop throught the array, summing up the total length. Once you are over the cutoff length, discard this array element and all subsequent ones, and build together your original filename. For easier debugging, I strongly recommend to write a shell script which does this operation for one single file, and then call the script from i.e. find. BTW, you did not specify how to deal with filenames which have a newline character in their name, and with filenames which have two subsequent spaces in their name.

What should be the new name if there is only one word, longer than n, e.g., foobar.txt with n=6? Do you want to rename as .txt, fo.txt or not rename at all? And what if two new names are the same?

@RenaudPacalet in my use case the name will be limited to 120 characters and the chances of these scenarios happening are zero.

Nice. I suggest that you add this important information to your question: 1. all file names contain spaces on the left of the cut position, 2. it is guaranteed that the new file names are different.

You were very close. Try this:
tmp="${f%.*} "
tmp=${tmp::n-${#ext}+1}
mv -- "$f" "${tmp% *}$ext"


Consider keeping it simple and finding files with find then truncating names with fold+head:
$ echo 'sample file name so long wrangling roose turns bridge.txt' | fold -s -w 40 | head -1
sample file name so long wrangling

then adding the .txt back, e.g. something like this, untested:
sfx='.txt'
lgth='120'
while IFS= read -r file; do
    trunc=$(printf '%s\n' "${file%%$sfx}" | fold -s -w "$lgth" | head -1)
    echo mv -- "$file" "${trunc}${sfx}"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*"$sfx")

That assumes your file names don't contain newlines.

bash can do the regex matching directly:
export n=120

find . -type f ! -name '.*' -execdir bash -c '
    declare -n m=BASH_REMATCH
    for f; do
        (( ${#f} > n )) || continue
        [[ $f =~ \.[^\ ./]+$ ]]
        (( max = n-1-${#m} ))
        [[ $f =~ ^(\./.{0,$max}[^[:space:]])[[:space:]].*("$m")$ ]] &&
        echo mv -- "$f" "${m[1]}${m[2]}"
    done
' - {} +


short alias for BASH_REMATCH
skip short filenames
find (optional) extension
calculate maximum head length
locate maximal head that ends in non-whitespace
(filenames with insufficient spaces are skipped)
do the rename


Nice but .{,n} is not POSIX and thus not portable, I am afraid. It works under GNU/Linux, for instance, but not under macOS. Replace with .{0,n}, maybe.

And even with .{0,...} this will also cut small file names: with n=120 and f="./a a.txt" it outputs mv -- ./a a.txt ./a.txt.

@RenaudPacalet hmmm, apparently I need coffee
