Extract up to last whole word below a certain character length in bash
I'm trying to copy some files with really long filenames but due to filename length constraints, I need to limit the maximum filename length (which is easy enough by itself) but I don't want the substring to end with a split word (for clarity, I'm just referring to any text separated by spaces as a "word")
For example, let's say that the maximum length is 30 characters and I have a 44-character string: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
If I just extract the first 30 characters, it would give me
The quick brown fox jumped ove but I just want the whole, non-split words so the output I need should just be The quick brown fox jumped
How exactly am I supposed to achieve this in bash?
I've tried doing it this way which I thought would work but didn't

filename="${names[$j]}"

filename="$(echo "${filename:0:100}") "

filename="${filename% *}"

I can't think of a regex but if there's something that would just let me fix this with sed, that would be much appreciated.
So my previous code just extracts the first 100 characters of the string and doesn't remove any trailing words that got split.

names[$j] what is j? why is it an array? :100}") " why space here?

@KamilCuk I think the space was added to prepare for the case when the character limit incidentally already cuts at a word's end (but as you pointed out, this causes issues for other cases).

what should happen to verylongnamenospaces  or a verylongnospaces or very long name.extensions ?

this question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78917452/10971581

@KamilCuk thanks for pointing those out. Yeah, $names was supposed to be the list of filenames and $j was just an iterator variable. I missed changing those variables to something clearer when I copied my code to paste it here.

@pmf what sort of other cases that may cause issues should I consider/anticipate?

@jhnc the max length for my actual use case would actually be 150 chars so theoretically, all strings that exceed the limit would have at least one space. Also, I'm already accounting for possible length variations for other parts of the filename so I'm good with the file extensions.

from my answer to the other question: s='The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'; n=30; ((${#s}>n)) && [[ $s =~ ^(.{0,$((n-1))}[^[:space:]])[[:space:]] ]] && printf 'new_s=[%s]\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" or you can look at one of the others

@jhnc Also, thanks a whole bunch for the link. I've been racking my head for an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure out how to do this because I couldn't find any similar cases to mine but the link your sent seems to have the same exact issue I did so I've found the answers now. Again, thanks for the save!

This question is similar to: bash script for shortening a filename to at most 'n' length but without clipping whole words. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jhnc cool! I feel like I can understand this  example better than the one you gave for the other question. If it's not too much though, do you mind me asking how this bit works: [[ $s =~ ^(.{0,$((n-1))}[^[:space:]])[[:space:]] ]] && printf 'new_s=[%s]\n'

@jhnc it feels like it's the exact same problem so at this point, I'm just trying to understand how the solution you gave works so I can adapt it to other cases I may come across in the future.

It's important to check the length; without the check, even short names will get shortened more. [[ string =~ regex ]] puts matches into array BASH_REMATCH (0 is whole match, 1,2,etc are capture groups). The regex looks for longest head of string that is no more than n-1 characters followed by an ending non-space and then a space. the capture group (...) discards that trailing space. the printf is just a sample use of the result. replace it with something more useful to you. The && prevents the action if there was no match

I'd use fold.
str='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
fold -w 30 -s <<< "$str"

outputs
The quick brown fox jumps 
over the lazy dog

And then extract just the first line.
It turns out that there's a trailing space there, so I'll pipe it into sed
truncated=$(fold -w 30 -s <<< "$str" | sed 's/ *$//; q')
declare -p str truncated

outputs
declare -- str="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
declare -- truncated="The quick brown fox jumps"

